# Getting Nested query result from Cosmos DB with property named "Value"

Tags: query, nosql, syntax, azure, cosmos-db

I have Cosmos Db collection, I am trying to query the "Key" "Value" pair from.
Working query:

```
SELECT ed
From c
JOIN ed IN c.ExtendedData
Where ed.Key = "MembershipTypeId"
```

And got result:

```
[
    {
        "ed": {
            "Key": "MembershipTypeId",
            "Value": "224"
        }
    }
]
```

I need to filter by "Key" and "Value", but "Value" appears to be a reserved keyword
Not working query:

```
SELECT ed
From c
JOIN ed IN c.ExtendedData
Where ed.Value = "224"
```

Got HTTP 400 with message: Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'Value'

Answer (score 3):

If property name is the same as reserved word (in this case Value),
following syntax could be used:

```
["Value"]
```

In the case above here is working query:

```
SELECT ed 
FROM c 
JOIN ed IN c.ExtendedData 
WHERE ed.Key = "MembershipTypeId" 
AND ed["Value"] = "224"
```